# Examples of good JPA Java Desktop Application

Tags: java, jpa

I have learnt JPA recently. Now I want to use it in one of my commercial product. But before proceeding, I want to see some example JPA Java Desktop applications so as to have a better understanding of using JPA in desktop applications.

I have searched google for this but all I found was tutorials on JPA with examples of entities.

I need some good real java desktop applications which have used JPA.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not exactly what you're expecting but I  suggest to check Christian Bauer's  [Hibernate and Swing demo app](http://relation.to/1433.lace) (and also have a look at [Jens Schauder's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268651/session-management-using-hibernate-in-a-swing-application/273780#273780) on SO).