# confused about Lazy loading

Tags: jpa, lazy-loading, eclipselink

While trying to do some tests on lazy loading, to check if i'm understanding it well, i got totally confused.

Here's the entities i'm using on my test:

```
@Entity
public class Family {
@Id
private int id;


@OneToMany(mappedBy="family", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<Person> members;

//getters & setters

public String toString(){
    String s="";
    for(Person p:getMembers()){
        s+=p.getFirstName();
    }
    return s;
}
}

@Entity
public class Person implements Comparable<Person>{
@Id
private int id;

private String firstName;
private String lastName;

@ManyToOne
private Family family;

//getters &setters
}
```

here's my main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
    em = factory.createEntityManager();

    Query q = em.createQuery("select f from Family f");
    List<Family> families= q.getResultList();

    em.clear();
    em.close();
    factory.close();

    for(Family f:families){
        System.out.println(f);
    }
}
```

What i understood from lazy loading, is that if an attribute is marked to be fetched lazily, and doesn't get accessed while it's managed, it won't be loaded in memory and any attempt to access it later won't work. Now what confuses me is that the test described above doesn't have any problem when accessing the lazy members attribute through the detached Family list, even after closing the EM and the EMF ! ... Is that normal? Am-i miss-understanding the lazy loading concept?

**Note :** I'm using a J2SE environment with an embedded DB. My provider is EclipseLink

Thanks in Advance
George

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that your toString method is not triggered before the factory is closed, such as if the entity is being logged.  I would not recommend triggering relationship in a toString method as this is error prone and can be triggered unexpectedly. Turning on EclipseLink logging will help show you where it gets accessed in the factory's lifecycle, assuming it is not part of the problem.

Comment: thank you very much for the help i've already read your answer in [here](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/261691/755570/#msg_755570) :-)

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that you are using the eclipselink agent, or using static weaving.  If you are using neither, then LAZY will not be weaved, and you will have EAGER.

Also EclipseLink supports access to LAZY relationships after the EntityManager is closed.
Although not after the factory is closed.  However if the object was in the cache, then it may work after being closed as well.  Also, if you have another factory open on the same persistence unit, then the persistence unit is still open.

Comment: I've found a similar question in [here](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/tree/160098/#page_top), and there was an answer (as a coincidence posted by a member named James also :-)) that said "Actually weaving is only required for lazy OneToOne/ManyToOne lazy will work in OneToMany without weaving.", and this is confirmed in [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Using_EclipseLink_JPA_Extensions_%28ELUG%29#What_You_May_Need_to_Know_About_EclipseLink_JPA_Lazy_Loading).

Comment: concerning the support for accessing LAZY relationships after the EntityManegr is closed, i have no problem with that, because i concider this as rather an advantage ... i just wanna ensure that if i don't access a lazy relationship it doesn't get loaded in memory, and appearently this is not happening, because even after closing the factory (which is unique when i tried it in my example), the family instances still are able to access their members, and as described above i didn't access any of them before closing the factory :(

Answer (score 0):

It might be because the JPA provider is not required to use lazy initialization. It is not a must requirement for a JPA provider but [a **hint**](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/FetchType.html).

The JPA is required to eagerly fetch data when `FetchType.EAGER` is specified, but is not required to lazily fetch data when `FetchType.LAZY` is specified.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I forgot to tell that my JPA provider is EclipseLink, which dooes support lazy loading AFAIK.